# jQuery nth-child selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Got a small confusing issue with jQuery and selecting/styling a column in a table.

The following code works:

```
   $(function() {
      $("table").delegate('th.selcol','click', function(e) {
         var iCol = $(this).parent().children().index(this)+1;
         $("table tr td:nth-child(10)").each(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("colhighlight");
         });
      });
   });
```

But this code, changing the nth-child(10) to nth-child(iCol) produces an error 
"uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child"

```
   $(function() {
      $("table").delegate('th.selcol','click', function(e) {
         var iCol = $(this).parent().children().index(this)+1;
         $("table tr td:nth-child(iCol)").each(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("colhighlight");
         });
      });
   });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
     $("table tr td:nth-child(" + iCol + ")").each(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("colhighlight");
     });
```

nth-child expects an integer, not a string, so you can use concatenation to solve your problem.

Comment: nth-child also accepts some keywords and an equation. See the below from the jQuery documentation:

`The index of each child to match, starting with 1, the string even or odd, or an equation ( eg. :nth-child(even), :nth-child(4n) )`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
"table tr td:nth-child("+iCol+")"
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it into this:

```
  $(function() {
    $("table").delegate('th.selcol','click', function(e) {
       var iCol = $(this).parent().children().index(this)+1;
       $("table tr td:nth-child(" + iCol + ")").each(function () {
         $(this).toggleClass("colhighlight");
       });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   $(function() {
      $("table").delegate('th.selcol','click', function(e) {
         var iCol = $(this).parent().children().index(this)+1;
         $("table tr td:nth-child("+iCol+")").each(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("colhighlight");
         });
      });
   });
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: @chrisk: great, would you mind selecting one of the answers as a solution?